# How to override a config file in library project?

Tags: android, android-library

My question may seem a bit odd; but I just want to find out the right way to achieve it. My troublesome scenario is as follows:

- I've a default configuration file in my library project. Let's say it was named as "a.properties".
- And my library project was used by a third party application project called "B".
- "B" developers got sick of my "a.properties" file and would like to override it on one day.

Since they don't have permission to change the configuration file located in my sealed jar file, they will put a new "a.properties" at somewhere in their "res" folder file to replace mine. However my API must somehow realize that the new configuration file should be read instead of the one I've got in the "res" folder of my library project.

Do you think having the path to that config file and its name exactly the same as one they already have in the library project will be enough to override that file?

Comment: I know an Android Library Project with source can get its resources overridden in a application project but its worth a test to see if its possible in a jar based library project.

Comment: Himmm... I'll give it a try. It seems eclipse chooses to put my library project as a jar dependency under libs/ folder. That jar file doesn't seem to have resource files though... I don't know how i can tell eclipse to include resource files wrapped within the jar itself. Btw, if we suppose that jar files are loaded into the classpath as they are in the normal jre; yeah they should be overridden right?

Comment: Well, i am sorry; i was mistaken. it is not placing jar files of those library projects in libs/ folder. It adds a reference to those projects; but still it seems that referenced jar file has no resource file either :)